Probability mass function for combinatorics problem
The question is as follows:
A small pond contains 15 fish: 10 blue fish and 5 red fish. A set of 5 fish are caught
at random. (Once a fish is caught it is not placed back in the pond.) Let K be the
number of blue fish that are caught. Write down the probability mass function, $p_K$.
My initial thoughts were that I should express the probability of picking k blue fish and 5-k red fish for each k. This would involve the combination formula.
My working answer (albeit wrong) was as such:
$$p_K(k)=\frac{15Ck}{15!}\times\frac{(15-k)C(5-k)}{(15-k)!}$$

You are somewhat on the right track: What are the answers to these questions --- (i) Total number of ways of catching 5 fish (ii) Total number of ways of catching $k$ blue and $5 - k$ red fish?

In combinatorics, it is always useful (and simple) to do some checks. Apply your formula for k=0, k=1 ... k=5 ; compute the sum. On the other hand, compute the total number of choosing 5 fishes in a set of 15 fishes (=C(15,5)) ; If the 2 numbers do not match, there is something wrong.

The random number of blue fish caught follows a hypergeometric distribution.
We reason as follows:  there are $\binom{15}{5}$ ways to choose $5$ distinct fish out of the $15$, without consideration to order.  Of these ways, we count the desired number of outcomes in which there are exactly $k$ blue fish, by noting that there are $\binom{10}{k}$ ways to select $k$ blue fish, and $\binom{5}{5-k}$ ways to choose $5-k$ red fish.  Since the choices of blue and red fish can be made independently of each other, the total number of desired outcomes is $$\binom{10}{k} \binom{5}{5-k}$$ and the desired probability is
$$\frac{\binom{10}{k}\binom{5}{5-k}}{\binom{15}{5}}, \quad k \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}.$$
We can conceptualize the fish as being numbered and labeled:
$$B_1, B_2, B_3, \ldots, B_{10}, R_{11}, R_{12}, \ldots, R_{15}.$$
The labeling ($B$ versus $R$) is for convenience, to help us remember that if a fish has a number from $1$ to $10$, it is blue, and if it has a number from $11$ to $15$, it is red.
Then, for example, if we caught exactly $k = 3$ blue fish, then there are $\binom{10}{3} = 120$ ways to select $3$ distinct blue fish from the $10$ available:
$$\{B_1, B_2, B_3\}, \{B_1, B_2, B_4\}, \ldots, \{B_1, B_2, B_{10}\}, \\
\{B_1, B_3, B_4\}, \{B_1, B_3, B_5\}, \ldots, \{B_1, B_3, B_{10}\}, \\
\{B_1, B_4, B_5\}, \{B_1, B_4, B_6\}, \ldots, \{B_1, B_4, B_{10}\}, \\
\ldots,\\
\{B_1, B_9, B_{10}\}, \\
\{B_2, B_3, B_4\}, \ldots, \{B_2, B_3, B_{10}\}, \\
\ldots,\\
\{B_8, B_9, B_{10}\}$$
and if we caught $5$ fish in total, there must be $2$ red fish caught, and there are $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ such choices:
$$\{R_{11}, R_{12}\}, \{R_{11}, R_{13}\}, \ldots, \{R_{11}, R_{15}\} \\
\{R_{12}, R_{13}\}, \ldots, \{R_{12}, R_{15}\} \\
\ldots
\{R_{14}, R_{15}\}.$$
So there are in total $120 \cdot 10 = 1200$ ways to catch exactly $3$ blue and $2$ red fish, out of a total of $\binom{15}{5} = 3003$ unrestricted ways to choose $5$ fish.
